# Delphi HTTPRIO Certificates

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, certificate, delphi-10.3-rio

I uptaded Delphi to the 10.3.2 version. My app worked well using a webservice with HTTPRIO and certificates in the previous version I was working with (10.1). I changed a few things to make it compile&run. But I'm facing a problem now.
I have a combobox with all the certificates in the machine so the user can select the one he needs.
The first time I only do this:

HTTPRIO1.HTTPWebNode.ClientCertificate.SerialNum:= CertificatSerialNumber;

and in the HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1NeedClientCertificate event I set the AnInteger value properly.

This way it works fine.

The thing is if the user selects another certificate, even I set the SerialNum property with the new value the OnNeedClient event is not triggered again so it still uses the first certificate. Is there a way to reset the certificate so I can set it every time I make the request depending on the combobox selection? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Should probably `.connect(false)` to close the connection before switching certificates if the connection is already active. I would not do it every time - re-using an existing connection saves the connection setup time.

Comment: hey, thank you, Brian! how can I access this connect method? I can't find it. which object/class is calling it and when it would be used?